# Unique constraint violation even failOnError is set to false

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class where i set a unique constraint on multiple columns.Even though failOnError is set to false when there is a duplicate data it still throws duplicate key entry violation.

```
// Domain
class Account {
    String userName
    String password
    String userAccount

    static constraints = {
        userName(nullable:false);
        password(nullable:false);
        userAccount(nullable:false);
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'custdata'
        userAccount(unique:['userName','password'])
    }
}

// Controller
Account account = new Account(userName: 'X', userAccount: '123', password: '3456');
account.save(flush: true, failOnError: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

These are two different things - 
1. when you set failOnError to false- no error will be thrown from the validation phase. 
2. When you do this  userAccount(unique:['userName','password']) - this makes a change in the underlying database layer by introducing a unique constraint. And when you try to save the duplicate data - the error is thrown from database.

Comment: Hi Alok how to fix it so that database wont throw duplicate key error?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your business logic, it requires that the username and password fields be unique at the database level.

What is not clear to me is whether you need the fields to be unique independently or together

If it were the first case you could delegate the responsibility to Constraints

```
static constraints = {
    userName nullable:false, unique: true
    password nullable:false, unique: true
    userAccount nullable:false
}
```

If it were the second case you could use a validator to add custom validation to a field

```
static constraints = {
    userName nullable:false
    password nullable:false, validator: { password, obj ->
        Account.where {
            password == password &&
            userName == obj.userName
        }.count() ? true : false
    }
   userAccount nullable:false
}
```

This second option I have not tested it if you implement it and you find a problem let me know and we work it